# Ways to check if an ArrayList contains only null values

Tags: java, android

I was looking through the code for an old Android application of mine, and I saw one thing I did to the effect of this:

```
        boolean emptyArray = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++)
        {
            if (array.get(i) != null)
            {
                    emptyArray = false;
                    break;
            }
        }
        if (emptyArray == true)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
```

There has to be a more efficient way of doing this -- but what is it?

emptyArray is defined as an ArrayList of Integers, which are inserted with a random number of null values (And later in the code, actual integer values).

Thanks!

Comment: By the way, you just use `if (emptyArray)` instead of `if (emptyArray == true)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no more efficient way.
The only thing is you can do, is write it in more elegant way:

```
List<Something> l;

boolean nonNullElemExist= false;
for (Something s: l) {
  if (s != null) {
     nonNullElemExist = true;
     break;
  }
}

// use of nonNullElemExist;
```

Actually, it is possible that this is more efficient, since it uses `Iterator` and the Hotspot compiler has more info to optimize instead using `size()` and `get()`.

Comment: _I will comment to my own answer_: putting it in functions as _Bohemian_ did, it is much more useful

Answer (score 25):

Well, you could use a lot less code for starters:

```
public boolean isAllNulls(Iterable<?> array) {
    for (Object element : array)
        if (element != null) return false;
    return true;
}
```

With this code, you can pass in a much wider variety of collections too.

---

Java 8 update:

```
public static boolean isAllNulls(Iterable<?> array) {
    return StreamSupport.stream(array.spliterator(), true).allMatch(o -> o == null);
}
```

Comment: I did edit it to swap them soon after posting, so yeah, but not any more. the final return should be true for a method called "isAllNulls" if it didn't find any nulls in the loop

Comment: Thanks!  Actually, this same project I had planned on going through to convert all the "for" loops to the "for each" loop syntax you use above.

Comment: Ughh ... unblocked `while` containing unblocked `if`.  Didn't your lecturers tell about how `{ }`-s protect you against misleading indentation?

Comment: @Stephen: in this case is not that bad that isn't in block, since it is a small function that won't change and and communicates the purpose well. I would just make it more general to use List<?>, so that will be useful for any List, and also declare it static

Answer (score 1):

It's not detection of *contains only `null` values* but it maybe be enough to use just `contains(null)` method on your list.

Answer (score 0):

Simply Check it worked for me. Hope will work fine for you too!

```
    if (arrayListSubQues!=null){
return true;}
else {
return false }
```

Answer (score -1):

I use to do something like this :

```
// Simple loop to remove all 'null' from the list or a copy of the list
while array.remove(null) {
    array.remove(null);
}

if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(array)) {
    // the list contained only nulls
}
```

Comment: I said to "remove all null from a copy of the list", since you want to work on it. You can also need to sort it or count stuff, without impacting the original list.

Comment: The question was not about removing (and I don't know why my previous comment has disappeared)